# Restrict images access in my website limit the user to access specific image by htaccess and php

Tags: php, .htaccess, chat, http-redirect

I am working on a chat website which has the feature of sending images to users which would be save into their user folder like this user/newuser/a.jpg (means whenever a user register I create a folder inside a main user folder name like this user/newuser).

But here the problem arises this image is meant to be seen by only sender and receiver not by everyone but everyone with the url can easily seen the image like this http://localhost/chat/user/abc.jpg.
So, I come up with that I would  restrict access to user folder with htaccess and redirect all requests to user/index.php with this code.

```
RewriteRule ^user(/.*)?$ user/index.php [QSA]
```

and from this user/index.php I will redirect user to user/username/userimage.jpg with this code.

```
session_start();
$imageName = str_replace('/chat/','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if(in_array($imageName,$_SESSION['imageArray'])){

/**$_SESSION['imageArray'] contains all images name which can be accessed by the logged in user like this 
    *['user/newuser/abc.jpg','user/newuser/1.jpg',]
*/
    header('location:'.substr($imageName,strrpos($imageName,'/')+1)); //just output image.jpg

}
else{
echo 'you are not allowed to access this resource';
}
```

But it isn't working the way it should be if the user can access image it is ending up redirecting again and again and if not then it simply saying `you are not allowed to access this resource`.

Now, if you understand my question hopefully tell me how to achieve this and if it can't be achieved with htacess then what should I do and what is the best and efficient way to handle scenarios like this.I don't want to use readfile functions to read file and anything like that because it will consump a lot of server resource.Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I know that htaccess is redirecting when image can be accessed because of my htaccess condition that any request to user folder should be redirect to user/index.php. But I don't want to redirect any request which is made inside user/index.php to access any of user folder resource. I am not good with .htaccess code so any code you provide it would be great if you would explain it too.

Comment: The simplest answer is "don't store public data in public locations" and then you don't have to worry about specially configuring your webserver to not accidentally serve that data. Store the file _outside of the docroot_ and use PHP to check access rights and deliver the data.

Comment: Can you help me with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some rough example code that approximates what it might look like to store and retrieve files stored outside the docroot of your website.

```
/home/someuser/
  - htdocs/
    - get_file.php
    - serve_file.php
  - var/user_files/
```

`get_file.php`

```php
$filename = tempnam('../var/user_file/', 'usrfile_');
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $filename);
$realname = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

YourApp::save_user_file_info($filename, $realname);
```

`serve_file.php`

```php
if( ! YourApp::check_auth() ) {
  exit();
}
$some_identifier = $_GET['id'];
$file = YourApp::get_user_filename_info($some_identifier);

session_write_close();
header('Content-type: ' . $file->mimeType);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
header('Content-length: ' . $file->size);
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="$file->realname"');
readfile($file->location);
exit();
```

Comment: Storing file real and fake names then reading every image by readfile is going to use a lot of server resources and I don't think it would be a good solution when there is a chance of thousand images. Can you help with any .htaccess magic because in my main chat file I am retriving images in img tag like this <img src= 'user/someuser/abc.jpg'>.

Comment: "going to use a lot of server resources" it really won't. You're talking about storing/retrieving literally 2 strings, and a very efficient core IO function. The worst you can say is that a PHP worker will also be busy for the few milliseconds it takes to serve a file, instead of just an Apache worker. You can even get around that with X-Sendfile, though it's not part of standard Apache. Besides, even if you _do_ gate public access with apache config you're still going to need a PHP file exactly like this to grant access anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer though I have another solution in my mind that is I would place user folder out of root folder of my project and I would create another folder inside root folder with name var.and from this var i will redirect user to their respected folder. In my chat file I will access image like this <img src= var/md5(a_secret_key_to_access_image). Tell me it's a good solution or not and thanks for your previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I come with a working solution. Check it out and if there are any bugs kindly inform me in comments.
Let's Start, this line in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^user(/.*)?$ user/index.php [NC]
```

is redirecting all requests from user folder to user/index.php and in this file this is the basic example of what I did there.

```
if(in_array($url,$_SESSION['accessible-images')){                
header('Content-Type: image');
echo readfile(str_replace('user/','',$imageName)); }               
     else{ 
   header('location:404'); }
```

with this code only user can access the images which they are allowed to access. And anyone who can't access images are sent to 404 page. Here is my code where I am retrieving images.

```
echo '<img src=\'user/username/userfile.jpg\' >';
```

Thanks to Mr Sammitch Answer which help with the header function. If this answer or question would help anyone please upvote my anwer and question too.Thanks

Comment: Readfile is most likely the better option compared to file_get_contents. Readfile loads directly into the output buffer where as file_get_contents loads into memory.